# Is there a way to tell WebStorm EAP where to find android_home?

Tags: android, cordova, webstorm

Anyone managed to solve the issue with ANDROID_HOME variable with WebStorm EAP?

I have set up the variable at my machine level, and did it at WebStorm level but does not work:

> *ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
>
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project*

Any idea?

Comment: How are you setting the ANDROID_HOME env variable?

Comment: .bash_profile and within Webstorm using the environment variable dialog

Comment: which OS are you running?

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem in Ubuntu 15.10. It worked nicely when I compiled the program from terminal, but not when I tried the same command from WebStorm IDE.

The solution was trivial, yet hard to find. If you start the program from the launcher (or desktop file), the environmental variables are not getting populated the same way as from the `.bashrc` file. That is why there was no `ANDROID_HOME` at all, and the `PATH` was also different.

The accepted answer from this thread solved my problem: [My .bashrc alias not run in .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/a/498718/117987)

Solution for Linux:

1. **Find the WebStorm IDE desktop file** (Mine was located at `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-webstorm.desktop`)
2. **Edit the Exec command** (Add `bash -ic` before the executable file: `Exec=bash -ic "/path/to/webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh" %f`)

Comment: I never did find the jetbrains-webstorm-desktop file but I found the webstorm.sh file and executed that in a terminal which fixed my problem thanks.

Comment: :O Wornderful!!

Comment: The only problem is `jetbrains-webstorm.desktop` file is reset by Jetbrains Toolbox on every reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path to your android sdk home from your root then what you need to do is as a root user edit the `/etc/profile` and add this line at the end

```
export ANDROID_HOME="path/to/my/sdk"
```

To edit the `/etc/profile` file you can use nano,

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

add the export line at the end of the file, then press `ctrl+o` on your keyboard to save and `ctrl+x` on your keyboard to close. 
Then restart your computer, you have successfully added the `ANDROID_HOME` env variable to your OS

Comment: what do you mean it does not care, just add environment variable like I asked, then remove whatever settings you did in the webstorm for this, you don't to have 2 configurations if you have set 1

Comment: running cordova run --emulator android
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Comment: @StephaneG oh is it getting compiled on an emulator then?

Comment: Yes the idea is to use webstorm EAP as an editor and run my app in the emulator ... on the paper it sounds viable :-)

Comment: Ok so the app runs on the emulator, but everything gets compiled in your machine where you set the environment variables yes? try adding these lines to the end of `/etc/profile`  `PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`    `export PATH`

Comment: @StephaneG so webstorm runs and compiles code written on it in the system where you set environment variables yes? And I think for the error message you posted in the comment above it has nothing do with Webstorm but with cordova. Cordova is the one that can't find your android sdk.

Comment: now for some bizarre reasons it's setup, I have manipulated many times my bash_profile and sourced it, now it's ok

Answer (score 0):

In **Linux**, one should mind the difference between a login and an interactive shell environments. The former is visible to any application in a session, the latter - only to a shell (and processes launched from that shell). The correct solution is moving your variables into a login environment (~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile etc.) and restarting a session.

Under **macOS**, all JetBrains IDEs explicitly load a shell environment. If some variable isn't visible to some IDE component, then it's a bug either in that component or in a code which loads the environment; both cases better be reported to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com.